# Tiny MCE to pick image from my computer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, tinymce

How to let tiny MCE pic image from my desktop or other folder from My computer rather than referencing it from other website?

And in this case how can I save images to the database to retrieve later?

I am using asp.net and SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have also http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcfilemanager.php
TinyMCE file manager.